# Urgent need on this word Perpeocue

Tags: single-word-requests

I am surprised reading a letter from a colleague in the office using a word **Perpeocueing** I don’t know if such word exists. I’ve searched google and my dictionaries and can’t find it.

The sentence reads: 
“*We crave your indulgence to guide us on how best to proceed as perpeocueing a memorandum of agreement with your respected office to carry out these services effectively*”.

I need urgent help. Thank you.

Comment: I think they've misspelled [procuring](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/procuring). Actually it should probably read "... as per procuring a memorandum...".

Comment: I just got him correct it. It reads “as per procuring”

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was asked on the basis of a false assumption, which has since been corrected (in a comment).

Comment: You can close it @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica